# VC++ Template Compiler Error C2244: Unable to Match Function Definition to an Existing Declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, compiler-errors

I've encountered a compiler error using Visual Studio 2010 which I've reduced down to the following code:

```cpp
template <int i> struct A
{
    typedef int T;
};

template<int i>
struct B
{
    static const int i = i; // <-- this seems to cause the problem
    typename A<i>::T F();
};


template<int i>
typename A<i>::T B<i>::F()       { return B<i>::i; }
```

This code produces this error:

```
repro.cpp(15): error C2244: 'B<i>::F' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
repro.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'B<i>::F'
      definition
      'A<i>::T B<i>::F(void)'
      existing declarations
      'A<i>::T B<i>::F(void)'
```

If the declaration for `i` in struct `B` is removed the compiler error goes away. I believe it's because the template parameter for the return type of `F` is binding to the static member `i` within `B` instead of `B`'s template argument. Why do the return types for `F` 'differ' when the value for `i` is the same? Is this a bug?

I should also mention that if the function is declared inline the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are declaring the same name twice in the same scope.  If you rename the static const int i, or the template parameter it should work.

Comment: Does that also explain why implementing the method inline in the class does not exhibit the error? I would've thought that where it's implemented would not have not have made a difference.

Comment: Yes.  You can overload a name in C++, but only if the overload occurs in a different scope.

Comment: Also, even though the i's may technically be different i's, their values are identical. Being that i is a nontype template parameter why does its identity matter as opposed to its value?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter that their values are equal (and from the compiler's perspective it doesn't even realize this).  It would still be an error if you wrote "int i = 1; int i = 1;" in the body of a function for example.