# Issue with template method definition - error C2244: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I have two template classes:

```
template<typename D, typename V, typename Comp>
class pQueueNodeComp;
```

and:

```
template <typename D, typename V, typename Comp>
class pQueueComp;
```

Inside `pQueueComp` I have a method declared as such:

```
pQueueNodeComp<D, V,Comp>* lowest();
```

and here's the definition:

```
template <typename D, typename V, typename Comp>
pQueueNodeComp<D, V, Comp>* pQueueComp<D, V, Comp>::lowest() {
    return binaryHeap[0]; //binaryHeap is a vector<pQueueNodeComp<D, V, Comp>*>
}
```

I'm getting the following error on Visual Studio 2015:

```
1>d:\github\pqueue\pqueue\pqueuecomp.h(163): error C2244: 'pQueueComp<D,V,Comp>::lowest': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>  d:\github\pqueue\pqueue\pqueuecomp.h(161): note: see declaration of 'pQueueComp<D,V,Comp>::lowest'
1>  d:\github\pqueue\pqueue\pqueuecomp.h(163): note: definition
1>  d:\github\pqueue\pqueue\pqueuecomp.h(163): note: 'pQueueNodeComp<D,V,Comp> *pQueueComp<D,V,Comp>::lowest(void)'
1>  d:\github\pqueue\pqueue\pqueuecomp.h(163): note: existing declarations
1>  d:\github\pqueue\pqueue\pqueuecomp.h(163): note: 'pQueueNodeComp<D,V,Comp> *pQueueComp<D,V,Comp>::lowest(void)'
```

It looks to me like the declaration matches the definition. Am I going crazy?

Edit: The definition of the class and the methods are in the same file.

Edit2: Here's the full definition of `pQueueComp`:

```
template <typename V, typename D, typename Comp>
class pQueueComp {
public:
    pQueueComp(Comp _cmp) :
        cmp(_cmp)
    {};
    pQueueNodeComp<D, V,Comp>* add(const D& data, V value);
    pQueueNodeComp<D, V,Comp>* lowest();


    void removeLowest();
    int size() { return binaryHeap.size(); };
    ~pQueueComp();
    pQueueComp() {};
    pQueueComp(const pQueueComp&) = delete; /*out of the scope of this project*/
    pQueueComp& operator=(const pQueueComp&) = delete;
    void print();
private:
    Comp cmp;

    std::vector<pQueueNodeComp<D, V, Comp>*> binaryHeap;

    void changeValue(int rank, V newValue);


    void goDown(int rank);
    void goUp(int rank);
    void swap(int rank1, int rank2);

    int parent(int i) { return (i + 1) / 2 - 1; };
    int child1(int i) { return 2 * (i + 1) - 1; }
    int child2(int i) { return 2 * (i + 1); }

    friend class pQueueNodeComp<D, V, Comp>;

};
```

I'm having issues with `lowest` and `add`.

Comment: The templated types of your decleration belong to the class which instansiate it, but the definition is using new types

Comment: @Rakete1111, probably not a duplicate. He mentioned that the definition of the class and the method is in the same file.

Comment: Do you have some `using`/`typedef` inside your class ?

Comment: @ZivS I'm sorry, can you be more specific? I don't see how the definition is using new types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108359/how-do-i-define-a-template-function-within-a-template-class-outside-of-the-class

Comment: @Jarod42 No typedefs or alias in any of the classes.

Comment: Here's an example where one of the names is redefined inside the class, [Error C2244](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475571/vc-template-compiler-error-c2244-unable-to-match-function-definition-to-an-ex), so that it looks the same, but means something else. Could that be it?

Comment: @BoPersson I added the full definition of the `pQueueComp` class to the OP. There is no name redefinition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following compiles and runs with VS15:
Header.h:

```
template <typename D, typename V, typename Comp>
class pQueueNodeComp
{
    D d;
    V v;
    Comp c;
};


template <typename D, typename V, typename Comp>
class pQueueComp
{
public:

    pQueueNodeComp<D, V, Comp>* lowest();
};

template<typename D, typename V, typename Comp>
pQueueNodeComp<D, V, Comp>* pQueueComp<D, V, Comp>::lowest()
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"
int main()
{
    pQueueComp<int, int, int> x;
    auto y = x.lowest();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I posted before seeing your edit2. Note that in your first example the template types are in one order, and in the actual code of pQueueComp the `V` and `D` template arguments are reversed

Comment: Reversing the template arguments did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: NP. As an unrelated tip - don't name your class with a `p` prefix just because you use it as a pointer. name the instance of a pointer to your class that way (if you like)

Comment: `pQueue` is shorthand for priority queue in this case (it has some extra functionality compared to `std::priority_queue`), but I guess it can be confusing. I'll name it something more explicit then. Thanks again.